# Can I grep only the last field of a .csv file?

Tags: bash, grep

I need to isolate lines of a file that end with a number less than 100
example: If I have these two lines:

```
2018-04-17 01:35:12 UDP 10.101.7.69 2135 83
2018-05-05 04:26:05 UDP 11.101.6.65 2160 104
```

I need to isolate and display only the one ending with 83. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, you can. What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '($NF<100) {print}' a.txt
```

Comment: Shortened a bit: `awk '$NF<100' a.txt`